# Android: Can't get the details of Email

Tags: android, return-value, android-cursoradapter

I created a ContactManager.java for display all the contact person details from phone and the SingleListContact is for display one of the clicked contact person. By now, I was able to get the Contact Person Name but not Contact Email, any guru can help me?

My ContactManager.java

```
    /*
     * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    package com.example.android.contactmanager;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

    public final class ContactManager extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
    {

        public static final String TAG = "ContactManager";

        private Button mAddAccountButton;
        private ListView mContactList;
        private boolean mShowInvisible;
        //public BooleanObservable ShowInvisible = new BooleanObservable(false);
        private CheckBox mShowInvisibleControl;

        /**
         * Called when the activity is first created. Responsible for initializing the UI.
         */

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {


            Log.v(TAG, "Activity State: onCreate()");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.contact_manager);

            // Obtain handles to UI objects
            mAddAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
            mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
            mShowInvisibleControl = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.showInvisible);

            // Initialise class properties
            mShowInvisible = false;
            mShowInvisibleControl.setChecked(mShowInvisible);

            // Register handler for UI elements
            mAddAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "mAddAccountButton clicked");
                    launchContactAdder();
                }
            });
            mShowInvisibleControl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "mShowInvisibleControl changed: " + isChecked);
                    mShowInvisible = isChecked;
                    populateContactList();
                }
            });

            mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
            mContactList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            // Populate the contact list
            populateContactList();
        }

        /**
         * Populate the contact list based on account currently selected in the account spinner.
         */
        private void populateContactList() {
            // Build adapter with contact entries
            Cursor cursor = getContacts();
            String[] fields = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,

            };


            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_entry, cursor,
                    fields, new int[] {R.id.contactEntryText});
            mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        /**
         * Obtains the contact list for the currently selected account.
         *
         * @return A cursor for for accessing the contact list.
         */
        private Cursor getContacts()
        {
            // Run query
            Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            //Log.i("Uri ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI" + ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null);

            String[] projection = new String[]
                    {
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
    //                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.DATA1
                    //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA
                    };
            String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
            //String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + (mShowInvisible.get() ? "0" : "1") + "'";
            String[] selectionArgs = null;
            String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

            return this.managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        }


        /**
         * Launches the ContactAdder activity to add a new contact to the selected account.
         */
        protected void launchContactAdder()
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactAdder.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("TAG", "You clicked item " + id + " at position " + position);
            // Here you start the intent to show the contact details
         // selected item
            //String contactDetails = (String)(mContactList.getItemAtPosition(position));
            //Uri contactDetails = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

            Cursor cursor = getContacts();

            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

    //        Log.i("Address", "Testing" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));
            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListContact.class);
    //        SingleListContact.PutDetails(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, name, address, position, null, null);
            SingleListContact.PutDetails(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, name, email);

            Log.i("Show Contact Clicked: ",  name + "Email: " + cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            // sending data to new activity
            //i.putExtra("Contact Person", contactDetails);
            startActivity(i);

        }



    }
```

and also the SingleListContact.java

```
package com.example.android.contactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SingleListContact extends Activity {

    static int ContactPhone;
    static String ContactID, ContactName, ContactEmail, ContactAddress;
    //@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_contact_view);

        EditText txtContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txtContact.setText(ContactName);
//        txtContact.setText(ContactEmail);

        Log.e("ContactEmail: " , ContactEmail);

//        EditText txtContact2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
//        txtContact2.setText(ContactPhone);

        EditText txtContact3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        txtContact3.setText(ContactEmail);

// 
//     
//        EditText txtContact4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
//        txtContact4.setText(ContactAddress);


        ImageView myImg= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        myImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
             //Launch Intent or whatever you want here
                 Log.e("GeoTag Button", "Clicked!");
//                                                      
                    double latitude = 13.042206;
                    double longitude = 80.17000;


                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude  + "," + longitude +"?z=10");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);                       
            }
         });

    }

    static void PutDetails (String id, String name, String email)
    {
        ContactID = id;
        ContactName = name;
        //ContactPhone = phone;
        ContactEmail = email;
//      ContactAddress = address;   
    }



}
```

the logcat:

```
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.example.android.contactmanager.ContactManager.onItemClick(ContactManager.java:148)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-05 05:00:31.289: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not able to retrieve Email id from Cursor because currently you are not querying Email column from contentprovider so change your code as:

```
private Cursor getContacts()
{
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]
            {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Email.DATA //<< query email data here

            };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP 
                + " = '" + (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";

    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
                                     + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return this.managedQuery(uri, projection, 
                      selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

Now you are able to get email id in ListView onItemClick method

Comment: are you means:   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA?

Comment: @SeanTan: yes until Email Column not exist in Cursor then it's not possaible to get it

Comment: that is where i found weird, after adding the ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, it still crash

Comment: @SeanTan : ok post new log and i saw you have added another method for retrieving email it . just comment emailid method and try it

Comment: @SeanTan : you are not getting me i think. point is very clear if a column if not exist in Cursor then how we get value of that column. so we first need to query Email column from ContentProvider to Cursor and then retrieve it from Cursor

Comment: i just add in the line u mentioned or i have to modify other parts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21695/discussion-between-sean-tan-and--k)

Comment: @SeanTan : after adding in  getContacts() method you will need to uncomment  `Log.i("Address", "Testing" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));` in onItemClick and check value you are getting or not . and also check manually in phone contact list selected contact have a Email id or not

Comment: i have add the line and also uncomment to check...but still the same...the contact person do have a email, btw, what u means by "check manually in phone contact list selected contact have a Email id or not"?

Comment: @SeanTan : i mean check on device contact list  selected number have a Email or Not ?